# Retain scroll position in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, window

I want to get **scrollY** position of current page after reloading page in angularjs.

I have tried using following

```
window.pageYOffset
```

But this returns 0 after reload. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Look for the  scrollTop value :)

Comment: After reload all your JS is wiped. You can try local storage. However, some browsers (e.g. last Chrome) retain scroll after refresh theirself. This,  of course, is only for body scroll.